# makefile compilation error for compiling on Arm board

Tags: c++, c, makefile, arm

I wanted to install rt8192cu driver on my ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS based OS (xillinux) running on an ARM processor (microzed board, zynq processor).

```
git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git
```

After I enter the above command and enter into the directory, and type make , i get the following error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3'
Makefile:579: /usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/arch/armv7l/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/arch/armv7l/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

The makefile can be found at https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu/blob/master/Makefile

The ubuntu based OS I am using is, http://xillybus.com/downloads/doc/xillybus_getting_started_zynq.pdf

How do I modify the makefile to compile directly on my platform ?

Comment: You probably need to run `configure` for cross-compilation before typing `make`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not trying to cross compile here. I want to directly compile on my platform. So how should I modify the make file to do so ?

Comment: Ah, I missed that point. Anyways running `configure` is the usual way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, If i try to do cross compiling on my ubuntu OS (virtualbox in windows), how do I do the cross compiling using configure ? I am new to cross compiling, so would need your help.

Answer (score 4):

even with linux-headers installed sometimes it fails, a quick workaround is this:

```
ln -s /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/arch/arm /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/arch/armv7l
```

a long workaround is to compile your own config from source with the same dot-config file and install all the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to compile a Linux Kernel Module for the RT8192CU Wi-Fi IC.
Moreover, you are running Ubuntu directly on the Zynq and you are trying to compile in place.

The error you receive is given by the lack of the Kernel headers, namely '3.12.0-xillinux-1.3', which should be the same kernel version you are using (try write uname -r in terminal).

The quickest way to solve is to let Ubuntu install the required sources/headers (provided the Kernel Module is targeting distribution-provided sources and you are running that specific kernel when issuing the following command) with

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Is it not more to do with the fact that the `arch/armv7l` subdirectory doesn't (and won't) exist? Which in itself rather implies that something has set `$ARCH` directly from uname instead of letting Kbuild figure it out properly.

Comment: @Notlikethat you may be right, overlooked that detail, I assumed the all kernel src directory was missing... Assuming the headers are present, he should be able to compile with a `make ARCH=arm` as you suggest.

Comment: Anyway, as an embedded developer I would suggest cross-compiling both kernel and out-of-tree drivers from a proper "controlled" environment, aka build machine.